# Performance penalty on misaligned data

Tags: c, performance, alignment

As a CS student I'm trying to understand the very basics of a computer. As I stumbled across [this website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/), I wanted to test those performance penalties on my own. I understand what he's talking about and why this happens / should happen.

Anyway, here's my code which I used to call those functions he wrote:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    uint8_t alignment = 0;
    uint8_t size = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10MiB
    uint8_t* block = malloc(size);

    for(alignment = 0; alignment <= 17; alignment++)
    {
        start_t = clock();
        for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            Munge8(block + alignment, size);

        end_t = clock();
        printf("%i\n", end_t - start_t);
    }
    // Repeat, but next time with Munge16, Munge32, Munge64
}
```

I don't know if my CPU & RAM are so blazingly fast, but the output of all 4 functions (Munge8, Munge16, Munge32 and Munge64) is always 3 or 4 (random, no pattern).

Is this possible? 100000 repetitions should be alot more work to do, or am I that wrong? I'm working on a Windows 7 Enterprise x64, Intel Core i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz. All compiler optimizations are turned off i.e. /Od.

All the related questions on SO didn't answer why *my solution* isn't working.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
First of all: Thank you very much for your help. After changing the type of size from `uint8_t` to `uint32_t` I altered all the inside loops causing undefined behaviour of the test functions to two separate lines:

```
while( data32 != data32End ) 
{
    data32++;
    *data32 = -(*data32);
}
```

Now I'm getting a relatively stable output of 25/26, 12/13, 6 and 3 ticks, calculating the average of 100 repetitions. Is this a logical result? Does this mean that my architecture handles unaligned access as fast (or as slow) as aligned access? Do I measure the time to inexactly? Or is there a problem with accuracy when dividing by 10? My new code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    uint8_t alignment = 0;
    uint64_t size = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10MiB
    uint8_t* block = malloc(size);


    printf("%i\n\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC); // yields 1000, just for comparison how fast my machine 'ticks'
    for(alignment = 0; alignment <= 17; alignment++)
    {
        start_t = clock();
        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            singleByte(block + alignment, size);

        end_t = clock();
        printf("%i\n", (end_t - start_t)/100);
    }
    // Again, repeat with all different functions
}
```

General criticism is, of course, also appreciated. :)

Comment: `uint8_t size = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10MiB` : range of uint8_t  : 0 - 255.

Comment: Looking at the linked article, the functions all contain undefined behavior with lines such as `*data8++ = -*data8;`. Additionally, the way you call them will make them access memory past the end of the allocated block.

Comment: @interjay why would `*data8++ = -*data8` be undefined behaviour ?

Comment: @interjay Good catch. It would seem that whoever wrote that article isn't a particularly experienced C programmer. So the article itself might be of questionable quality: read it sceptically.

Comment: Anyway, because of the fatal bug that BLUEPIXY pointed out, this question needs to be rewritten so that the mentioned bug is fixed. In its current state, nobody can really answer it, since the bug likely breaks the whole program and causes unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for that information, I thought that the `=` is a sequence point and that `-*data8` would be evaluated first and then  the assignment with postincrement of `data8` takes place.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Somehow I managed to delete my comment... Anyway, = does not come with a sequence point, so the expression is UB. The expression needs to be split into several lines.

Comment: @Lundin It is defined imo: `*data8++ = -*data8` is incrementing the pointer and not the value. `-` doesn't change the value. The expression is identical to `*data8 = -*data8; *data8++` which is also defined.

Comment: @2501 The variable is a pointer. The side effect of the expression is the increment of the pointer. On the right-hand side, the pointer is accessed for other purposes than to determine what value to be stored _in the pointer_ variable. So to break the expression down , the `data8++ ... data8;` part is what makes the UB, while the assignment etc is well-defined.

Comment: @Lundin I was wrong *The evaluations of
the operands are unsequenced.*

Comment: @Lundin Jup, I have just read that in the standard. Thank you for pointing it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This fails due to integer overflow:

```
uint8_t size = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10MiB
```

it should be:

```
const size_t size = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10MiB
```

No idea why you'd ever use an 8-bit quantity to hold something that large.

Investigate how to enable all warnings for your compiler.

Comment: BLUEPIXY already mentioned this in the comments of my question. The edit is all about this change (which took place close to the time you answered :) ).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with your clock function. **1000** for *CLOCKS_PER_SEC* is way too low for your processor even if CPU throttling is activated (you should get around 2100000 if frequency scaling is turned off). How much cycles do you get for each averaged mesure by using [cycle.h](http://www.fftw.org/cycle.h) ?